# Postgresql prepare statement with operator ANY

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement

SELECT * FROM tbl_emp WHERE interest = $1 AND emp_id = ANY(?)

Is the above statement correct to be used in function PQprepare?

If yes, what should be the value for nParams and how would PQexecPrepared be called?

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to prepare something like `= ANY (1, 2, 3)`, this won't work directly, because `1, 2, 3` is a syntactic construct, and not an expression.  (Of course you could do `= ANY ($2, $3, $4)`, but that only works if you know exactly how many values you have.)

But you can do it with arrays.  The above is equivalent to `= ANY(ARRAY[1, 2, 3])`, and so you'd write

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_emp WHERE interest = $1 AND emp_id = ANY($2)
```

and the types of the parameters are, say, `int` and `int[]`.

To call `PQexecPrepared`, you will need an array as string literal.  Something like `"{1, 2, 3}"` (as a C string) will do.  See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. Whatever you told worked perfectly well. (Though I could not vote it up as it needed 15 reputations). Well I'm thinking of using PQexec and passing PREPARE and EXECUTE statements, instead of using PQprepare and PQexecPrepared. Will it be a practical performance issue.